# How to add a new signal handler to gunicorn?

Tags: python, signals, gunicorn

I need a way to set number of workers for a gunicorn master process.

So I'm thinking of overriding the arbiter and adding a new signal handler, which read the new number of workers from a file.

Which signal would be a proper one to use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

From http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html

> the signal HUP can be used to reload the Gunicorn configuration on the fly
>
> Sending an HUP signal will reload the configuration, start the new worker processes with a new configuration and gracefully shutdown older workers.

You need to set the `workers` variable in the configuration file to the appropriate value before you signal the master process.